# Excel - I am trying to SUM values in a column if the values in a corresponding column equal the values in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I am trying to SUM values in a column if the values in a corresponding column equal the values in another column.

If the values in Column K (Fig 1) are found in Column F (Fig 2), SUM all the corresponding values of column L (Fig 1) in Z2 (Fig 3).

=SUMIF(K:K,F:F,L:L) is not giving me what I need.

Fig 1

[image: Fig 2]

Fig 2

[image: Fig 3]

Fig 3

[image: Fig 1]

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the incorrect result?

Comment: The expected result in Z2 is 38, the incorrect result when I use the SUMIF formula is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUMIF` provides an array of values, which would spill over to the follwing rows.
If you wrap it in `SUM`, you should get the desired result.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(L:L,K:K,F:F))
```

[image]

Side note: I prefer using `SUMIFS` over `SUMIF`, but both should work.